# as3 - Access class attributes dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, class, dynamic, attributes

```
public class SndFx
{
    [Embed(source="Sounds/01.mp3")]
    public static const s01:Class;
    public static const s01s:Sound = new s01() as Sound;

    [Embed(source="Sounds/02.mp3")]
    public static const s02:Class;
    public static const s02s:Sound = new s02() as Sound;

    [etc...]
}
```

Can I access these attributes dynamically? I've got a number of which sound I want to play, and I want to do something like this:

```
SndFx["s"+numberStr+"s"].play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that, although I'm not certain that it's actually impossible. But a way around it would be to have a singleton with a typical static method to access the instance.

```
SndFx.getInstance()['s'+numberStr+'s'].play();
```

A better approach though is to populate an array, or even a Flash Player 10 Vector, with your Sound objects, and to access the objects using that.

```
SndFx.soundEffectsArray[parseInt(numberStr)].play();
```

That allows you to check whether the parsed integer is out of bounds, et c.

Comment: Populating a dictionary is what I ended up doing. You can access properties dynamically with this[""].